# Remove edit mode on column in gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridView filled from an SQL query. I have made many of these columns editable so values that are changed can be updated back to my SQL DB.

What I want, is that I still want to show all my columns, but I only want to be able to highlight the columns I want for edit.

If I press edit now, I can edit in all my columns (not update them though because they are not included in the SQL Update statement)

Normally i just use `AutoGenerateColumns=true` - However I just read something about `BoundField` where its a possibility to write `Visible=false` - However this hides the column, and not the edit option.

As the blue arrows show - You can see its possible to edit those columns, and I dont want that. But i still want to show the columns data.

[image]

Comment: ReadOnly="true"  or if you used EditItemTemplate then removed it.

Comment: Add gridview code in question so, identify issue easily

Comment: @A.M.Patel ReadOnly is the correct thing. I just founded it before you wrote it!! Doooh how could i miss that one :) Thanks a lot!